# dropdownlist doesn't lost his selected value but listbox does

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have 2 user control one has dropdownlist other listbox, on main page there is a button when I click to button page goes postback and get user controls from session add controls on page. and I can get selected items from drop down list but list box cant sync with viewstate I guess.

what did I try;
binding session uc in page init, adding listbox datavalue and datatext, viewstate enable for listbox(which is default also i guess)

if you think logic is right so I must be doing something wrong in my code let me know I will try to paste it here in a simplified version.

Answer (score 0):

Here's code that does what you're trying to do, maybe you're not doing something correct and you can spot something to help you out.

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var newListBox = new ListBox();
            newListBox.ID = "ANewId";
            newListBox.Items.Add("1");
            newListBox.Items.Add("2");
            newListBox.SelectedIndexChanged += LstBoxChanged;
            Panel1.Controls.Add(newListBox);
        }

        private void LstBoxChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var newListBox = sender as ListBox;

            if (newListBox != null && newListBox.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                Label1.Text = newListBox.SelectedItem.Text;
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps.